# the meaning of "yet"

Tags: adverbs, conditional-constructions

*I have **yet** to meet the man I wish to marry.*

Could you clarify to me the meaning of the word "yet" in the sentence above which works here in a different way than it does usually. What is the meaning of the whole sentence? Is it something like "I have to finally meet the man I wish to marry"?

Comment: The meaning is "I haven't yet met the man I would wish to marry", and implies that this event (meeting the man) lies somewhere in the future. Or "at this point in time, I am still in a condition of looking/waiting for the man I would wish to marry"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two sentences have the same meaning

> I have **yet to meet** the man I wish to marry
>
> **So far**, I have **not met** the man I wish to marry, but I **still hope to in the future**

**Yet** is a conditional for *something* that **has not happened in the past** but will **hopefully happen in the future**

> I **have to** finally meet the man I wish to marry

has a meaning of **obligation** or **dependency**
**have to** = **must**
This sense of urgency is not necessarily conveyed by using **yet**, **yet** is more hopeful.